# Admissible heuristic for number maze/jumping maze problem

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a problem where a maze is given and every cell has a number. At any cell, you can jump up/down/left/right as many cells as specified in the current cell. What could be a good admissible heuristic to reach the goal using A*?

I have tried Manhattan/Euclidean distance, but I believe they overestimate the cost.

Comment: _you can jump up/down/left/right as many cells as specified in the current cell_ when do you mean ? please give example(s)

Comment: Can you guarantee no obstacles within the jump. If I jump 3 left and there's a wall at 2? Do I jump through it? It sounds to me more like a Speed of Travel variable, combined with distance from goal. So higher value squares are favoured.

Comment: @MatthewPage There are no obstacles in the maze. Just cells with numbers specified which denotes the allowed number of cells it can jump in any of the 4 directions. Also, one jump is equal to 1 cost and not the number of cells it actually jumps.

Comment: @bruno suppose you are at (0,0) and the cell has value 2 then it can jump to coordinates (2,0) or (0,2).

Comment: @antsy ok. What indicates the exit ? from where one starts ?

Comment: @bruno it starts from (0,0) and when it reaches a cell whose value is "G" i.e. goal, it exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple lower-bound would be the Manhatten distance divided by the size of the largest jump on the map (rounded down).  This should also be a consistent heuristic.

Comment: Yeah but I feel this might be over-optimistic.

Comment: @antsy If by "over-optimistic" you mean "non-admissible", then no, it is clearly admissible.  For example, if the manhatten distance is 10 and the largest jump on the graph is 2, there is no way to make it there in only 4 jumps.  5 is the absolute minimum possible.  In fact, it should be possible to show that this heuristic is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic), which is stronger than admissibility.

Comment: Let us suppose the maximum jump mentioned in a 8*8 matrix is 8. Then by this rule, I might get the same heuristic cost (0) for a large number of cells. So our heuristic won't uniquely identify which path to proceed. I get your point that this is admissible as it never overestimates, but it gives me the same heuristic cost for various choices too.

Comment: @antsy: Yes, that's correct. There's nothing wrong with that - the algorithm will devolve to Dijkstra's Algorithm once you're near the goal-node.  You could refine it a little bit by taking into account the node's value (`1+(manhattenDistance - nodeValue)/largestNodeValue`).